# Appium iOS on Bitrise returns false when checking element displayed

Tags: ios, automation, appium, bitrise

Currently I'm using WebDriverWait (`XCUITest`) to wait for displaying an element on iOS app.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("priority 1 program")));
```

This works on local machines, but not work on Bitrise server.
With logs from Bitrise, I realize that Appium did return the element (found) but not display in the screen (`isDisplay` returns `false`).

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["name","priority 1 program","7b75a5af-448a-4d48-9187-3bbb84aa5519"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'findElement'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, name, class name, -ios predicate string, -ios class chain, accessibility id
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/103F53F0-47D8-4604-8CB7-8AB5794DDD9F/element] with body: {"using":"name","value":"priority 1 program"}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"F30723B8-E7B0-4299-B260-AE3455918DBF"},"sessionId":"103F53F0-47D8-4604-8CB7-8AB5794DDD9F","status":0}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"F30723B8-E7B0-4299-B260-AE3455918DBF"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7b75a5af-448a-4d48-9187-3bbb84aa5519/element 200 2540 ms - 122 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/7b75a5af-448a-4d48-9187-3bbb84aa5519/element/F30723B8-E7B0-4299-B260-AE3455918DBF/displayed {}
[MJSONWP] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'proxyReqRes'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/7b75a5af-448a-4d48-9187-3bbb84aa5519/element/F30723B8-E7B0-4299-B260-AE3455918DBF/displayed] to [GET http://localhost:8100/session/103F53F0-47D8-4604-8CB7-8AB5794DDD9F/element/F30723B8-E7B0-4299-B260-AE3455918DBF/displayed] with body: {}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : false,\n  \"sessionId\" : \"103F53F0-47D8-4604-8CB7-8AB5794DDD9F\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
```

So I checked the screenshot, surprisingly the element is displayed without any views overlapped.

[image: Navigation bar title]

I have already tried different kinds of environment but it's the same.

- mac os 10.12.6,10.13.2
- appium 1.7.2, 1.7.0
- Xcode 9.2, 9.0.1
- iOS 11.2, iOS 11.0

I have also made some searches from Internet but it seems that no solutions work.

```
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9377
https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/746
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4131
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several not fixed issues related to element visibility, it can be related to [issue](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/582) in **WebDriverAgent** or the one you mentioned, still not fixed.

As a workaround you can:

- set **simpleIsVisibleCheck** capability to false and check if helps
- switch to `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated()` and basically only wait until element is present, skip `isDisplay` property